# Lisp: APPLY error when trying to generate a a-list using acons and loop

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I try to run this code in clisp:

```
(defun gen-world
(loop for x to *hight*
    do (loop for y to *width*
        do (acons '(x . y) '(rock) *world*))))
```

And get the following error:

```
*** - APPLY: argument list given to SYSTEM::ERROR-OF-TYPE is dotted
  (terminated by
   "Invalid specialized parameter in method lambda list
   (LOOP FOR X TO *HIGHT* DO
    (LOOP FOR Y TO *WIDTH* DO (ACONS '(X . Y) '(ROCK) *WORLD*))): (LOOP FOR Y IN
      *WIDTH* DO (ACONS '(X . Y) '(ROCK) *WORLD*))"
   )
```

When I run

```
(acons '(x . y) '(rock) *world*)
```

I get no errors

Why do this happen?
EDIT: `*hight*` `*width*` and `*world*` are global and in scope. `*world*` is a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see two problems here.

1. You are missing an argument list, so the `LOOP` form is taken as the argument list instead.  And it happens to contain a dotted pair `(X . Y)` which is not allowed.
2. Your key is a constant `'(X . Y)` when you probably wanted a pair containing the (integer) *values* of `X` and `Y`.

Try this:

```
(defun gen-world ()
    (loop for x to *hight*
        do (loop for y to *width*
            do (acons `(,x . ,y) '(rock) *world*))))
```

Comment: also ACONS has no side-effects. Thus the LOOP will do nothing.

Comment: I feel quite embarrassed right now, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with your function definition, you're missing the (empty) parameter list:

```
(defun gen-world () <body>)
```

Also in this line:

```
(acons '(x . y) '(rock) *world*)
```

End the expression with a list:

```
(acons '(x . y) '(rock) (list *world*))
```

And make sure that the variables `*hight*` [sic], `*width*` and `*world*` are in scope

Comment: When I run `(acons '(x . y) '(rock) *world*)` I get no problem and it generates just what I want.

Comment: @lonjil also, put a `()` after `gen-world` to indicate this is a procedure definition with no arguments

Comment: @lonjil if this solved your problem, please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark to its left